# Sorting an array of objects by property?

Tags: javascript, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

1. What is the best way to sort "rows" by either field1, field2, or field3?
2. What if field1, field2, or field3 is a non-numeric value (string or date), how can I make it possible to sort by these different data types?

   ```
   var Id = 0;
   var rows = new Array(); // I want to sort this array by either field1, field2, or field3
   rows[0] = (1, 3, 5);
   rows[1] = (-2, 4, -6);

   function Row(field1, field2, field3) {
       this.RowId = Id++;

       this.Field1 = field1;
       this.Field2 = field2;
       this.Field3 = field3;
   }
   ```

Comment: `(1,3,5)` is an expression that evaluate to `5`. Are you sure you don't mean `[1,3,5]`, or maybe `new Row(1, 3, 5)`?

Comment: Good call, thanks for the link, I should have done a more thorough search.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense so the question can't be answered until you fix/clarify.  `rows[0] = (1,3,5);` does not put multiple elements into `rows[0]`.  Did you mean `rows[0] = [1,3,5];`?  Or did you mean `rows[0] = {field1:1, field2:3, field3:5};`?